# Error when trying to enable dynamic constraint on Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have different Dynamic Constraints in Hybris. Especially when I want to enable a constraint which another constraint has the same **Annotation class** and Class to validate attributes, I am getting error as I shared logs below

```
Caused by: de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: [de.hybris.platform.validation.interceptors.AbstractConstraintUniqueValidator@778b3552]: Duplicated constrainted violation for a type constraint id: couponEANCheck [de.hybris.platform.couponservices.model.AbstractCouponModel ] @de.hybris.platform.validation.annotations.Dynamic groups: [[]] 
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.wrapper.ModelWrapper.invokeValidateInterceptors(ModelWrapper.java:302) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.wrapper.ModelWrapper.validate(ModelWrapper.java:239) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.extractor.impl.DefaultModelExtractor.process(DefaultModelExtractor.java:57) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelService.performPersistenceOperations(DefaultModelService.java:710) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelService.saveAllInternal(DefaultModelService.java:705) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelService.saveAll(DefaultModelService.java:685) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelService.saveAll(DefaultModelService.java:647) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.object.DefaultPlatformObjectFacadeStrategy.executeWithWorkflowTemplateActivation(DefaultPlatformObjectFacadeStrategy.java:228) ~[classes/:?]
at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.object.DefaultPlatformObjectFacadeStrategy.save(DefaultPlatformObjectFacadeStrategy.java:162) ~[classes/:?]
... 114 more
```

Since the **getConstraintDuplicates** method is fetching results, to prevent this I overrode it which is in **DefaultConstraintDao** class and changed the query.

My question will be that is it a proper way to enable more than one constraint at the same time which has same **Annotation class** and **Class to validate**?

Could this cause a problem in Hybris, after overriding and allowing the user to enable constraints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DefaultConstraintDao#getConstraintDuplicates method validates it. Seems like it's not allowed on purpose.